# Sed to replace this pattern with null

Tags: regex, linux, sed

A string with this format

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,pattern:[[xxxxxxxxxxxx],[yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy]],eee,fff,pattern:[[eeeeeeeeee],[fffffffff]]
```

How can I use sed to replace pattern:`[[ ???????????? ]]` with null

**Example**

`sed s/pattern:[[ ????????? ]]//g`

I tried `sed s/pattern:\[\[\([^]]*\)\]\]//g`
but it does not work.

Comment: Try with Perl, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/E3jnUu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` as `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matching:

```
s='aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,pattern:[[xxxxxxxxxxxx],[yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy]],eee,fff,pattern:[[eeeeeeeeee],[fffffffff]]'

perl -pe 's/pattern:\[\[.*?\]\]//g' <<< "$s"

aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,,eee,fff,
```

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with perl,  need to study more about it.

Comment: Command line `perl` works same as `sed` in this case. Regex also becomes quite simple (as you can see from other `sed` based answers). To try it out just copy/paste into your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a test file:

```
$ cat file
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,pattern:[[xxxxxxxxxxxx],[yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy]],eee,fff,pattern:[[eeeeeeeeee],[fffffffff]]
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed 's/\]\]/\n/g; s/pattern:\[\[[^\n]*\n//g; s/\n/]]/g' file
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,,eee,fff,
```

#### How it works

Because sed does not have non-greedy regular expressions, we have to use a trick:

- `s/\]\]/\n/g`

  This replaces all occurrences of `]]` with a newline.
- `s/pattern:\[\[[^\n]*\n//g`

  This replaces all occurrences of `pattern:[[` followed by any non-newline characters, `[^\n]*`, followed by a newline, `\n`, with an empty string.
- `s/\n/]]/g`

  If any newline characters, `\n`, happen to remain, this changes them back to `]]`.

Answer (score 0):

With ***awk***:

```
awk -v RS='pattern:\\[\\[|\\]\\]' 'NR%2' ORS= s1 file
```

- `RS='pattern:\\[\\[|\\]\\]'` - treating `pattern:[[` and `]]` as complex record separator (based on regex alternation group `...|...`)

The output:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,,eee,fff,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that it always looks has sets of square brackets like

```
pattern:[[abc],[def],...,[stu],[vxy]]
```

then you could do something like this:

```
sed 's/pattern:\[\{2\}[^]]*\(\],\[[^]]*\)*\]\{2\}//g'
```

That is a pattern starting with 2 '[' followed by anything that is not a closing bracket followed by optionally '],[' and anything that is not a closing bracket and finishing with ']]'

**Update:**

With the revised requirements to support the following 3 types of pattern:

- pattern:[[aaa],[bbb],...,[xxx],[yyy]]
- pattern:[[aaaaa]]
- pattern:[]

the solution is:

```
sed 's/pattern:\[\{1,2\}[^]]*\(\],\[[^]]*\)*\]\{1,2\}//g'
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this is the best way. I forgot to mention it needs to handle all this 3 types of pattern - pattern:[[xxx],[yyy]]   pattern:[[aaaaaaa]]  and pattern[].      This works out the best  **sed  's/pattern:\\[\{1,2\}[^]]*\(\],\[[^]]*\)*\]\{1,2\}//g'**

Comment: rather than posting it in a comment, its better practice to have an "Update:" section in your original question and detail your requirements there which patterns you require. The more details your original question has the better people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\[\[[^]]*\]\(,\[[^]]*\]\)*\]//g' file
```

The regexp follows the pattern (re Friedl):

```
sed 's/normal(special normal)*/replacement/g' file
```